# Split TF.string by regex pattern as delimiter

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to split string by regex pattern in Tensorflow(TF). I found [tf.string_split()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_split)

But, it expects delimiter as string not regex. How to do that in TF 1.2.

### Code Sample :

```
data = tf.Variable("aa the boy aaa the boy aaaaa")
data_split = tf.string_split(data, re.compile("a*"))
TypeError: Expected string, got re.compile('.') of type 'SRE_Pattern' instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

As of august 2017 there is no op in tensorflow to do this, but it's straightforward to implement one by copying the C++ code in StringSplit and editing it. Alternatively you can use `tf.py_func` to split in python instead of tensorflow.